# Selecting nodes based on multiple attributes of a node using MiniXPath library

Tags: xml, java-me, xpath

I have a XML document which looks something like this:

```
<events>
    <event category="gymnastics" subcategory="rhythmic" date="5" venue="ig stadium">
        <id>1</id>
    </event>
    <event category="gymnastics" subcategory="test" date="6" venue="jn stadium">
        <id>2</id>
    </event>
    <event category="athletics" subcategory="sprint" date="5" venue="ig stadium">
        <id>3</id>
    </event>
    <event category="athletics" subcategory="marathon" date="6" venue="jn stadium">
        <id>4</id>
    </event>
    <event category="swimming" subcategory="freestyle" date="7" venue="ig stadium">
        <id>5</id>
    </event>
</events>
```

So now when I issue a XPath query to MiniXPath like this in order to get nodes with category=gymnastics and subcategory=rhythmic:
//events/event[@category="gymnastics" and @subcategory="rhythmic"]

,the program crashes and fails to give any output. Is the path syntax right? Is MiniXPath feature complete? Is there any other XPath library that I can use on a mobile in a J2ME environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://minixpath.sourceforge.net/

> Features
>   - supports child::, descendant::, attribute::, parent:: as axes;
>   - supports *, node(), text() as node tests
>   - good support for namespaces
>   - supports simple expressions as predicates (i.e. [@city=rome])

Also, from source it looks like it doesn't handle logical operators.

Comment: yeah. looks like i will spend some time working the feature in it, and might as well add to the project. thanks again.